# How can Maven handle project / customer specific web.xml deployment descriptor in WAR

Tags: maven, project, web.xml

I have two questions ;-)

1. Is the "web.xml" in a WAR-File intended to contain project/customer-specific informations

   - Example: For customerX we want Filters for Bandwith and Compression for customerY we dont want those Filters
2. How does the Maven-Build-Process allow us to make different Builds for such project/customer-specific WAR-Files.

   - Should it be done with maven profiles
   - Should it be done with separate build-processes that integrate the release-project into individual WAR-Builds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To first one i would recommend to say No. You should solve that by using property files to handle such things.
you can handle that with profiles, but with the draw-back that you need to rebuild for every customer you have. Lets say dev, test, prod. This can be solved by properties but that means to build three times..I have described a better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705651/multiple-src-main-resources-folders-without-profiles-i-wish-to-build-multiple-v/9705954#9705954) which handles the different locations with a single build. That will solve the problem for release as well. 
It is also a solution to use a separate maven project (lets call it configuration module) which depends on the WAR file). But this would mean to three different projects like dev, test and production which i find not very handy.

Comment: thx, your solution is good if you have a fixed number of projects (dev,test,production) but the build-process would get a bit time-consuming if you have for example 50 customers where each customer needs its own web.xml configuration ;-) it seems to me that the web.xml of WAR-format is mainly not intendet for customer-specific configurations, as it is bundled within the war-file and can therefore not be changed after the build-process. But it makes me wonder, because the filter section in the web.xml would be really cool if you could provide customer-specific filter-configurations

Comment: i should have mentioned that with customer-specific i mean, that the WAR (which contains our Webshop-Backend) will be deployed on on a servletcontainer/appserver (Jetty,Tomcat,Jboss,Geronimo,Glassfish) that will be run on a webserver. This webserver is sold to our customer. And so every customer gets its own WAR-File (with customer-specific web.xml config).